# action bar progress bar not shown when compiled with API 21 (Android 5.0.1)

Tags: android, android-appcompat

How to enable progress bar in actionbar when compiled with appcompat api 21, android 5.0.1. I tried to follow the material design but i dont have values-21 folder in my project. Any help can be appreciated.